# Can I remove the top and bottom padding of a custom NSMenu?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I want to make a custom pop-up menu that has light text on a dark background.  I am aware of the `setView:` method of `NSMenuItem`, which I could use to make each item draw with light text on a dark background.  However, `NSMenu` draws 4 pixel high strips at the top and bottom of the menu in a light color, which pretty much ruins the look.  Since `NSMenu` doesn't have any public drawing methods I could override, I can't see how to get rid of those strips.

I see that the `NSMenu` header has private instance variables named `noTopPadding` and `noBottomPadding`.  So tantalizing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using an undeclared method (not ideal, obviously).  First declare it as follows:

```
@interface NSMenu (secret)
- (void) _setHasPadding: (BOOL) pad onEdge: (int) whatEdge;
@end
```

Then, sometime before showing the menu, do:

```
if ([menu respondsToSelector: @selector(_setHasPadding:onEdge:)])
{
    [menu _setHasPadding: NO onEdge: 1];
    [menu _setHasPadding: NO onEdge: 3];
}
```

My testing shows that this doesn't work on Snow Leopard, but does work on Lion, Mountain Lion, and Mavericks.

Comment: You can use this in Swift too, if you declare the `(secret)` interface in an Objective-C header you include in your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77)

Comment: @Dov how do you use it in Swift? I imported bridge header, however I'm still getting 'use of unresolved identifier _setHasPadding '

Comment: @Neeson.Z I'm not sure how you would accomplish this using a 100% Swift solution, since you don't have the ability to define a method's header without the implementation. Your best bet would probably be to define the category above in your bridging header (or a header your bridging header imports).

Comment: In macOS Mojave and later, you get menus that have light text on a dark background if you set the overall application appearance to dark.

Comment: "Then, sometime before showing the menu, do:"  - could you please elaborate more on this. I am not understanding where i should call the above IF condition.

Comment: @AnanthKamath: in my case I had a subclass of `NSPopUpButtonCell`, and set the padding in `awakeFromNib` and `setMenu:`.  Maybe it could also be done in a menu delegate `menuWillOpen:` or `menuNeedsUpdate:` method, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: @JWWalker thank you. I got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the method of @JWWalker you can do this in Swift by creating header file like this:

`NSMenu.h`

```objectivec
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#ifndef NSMenu_h
#define NSMenu_h

@interface NSMenu (secret)
    - (void) _setHasPadding: (BOOL) pad onEdge: (int) whatEdge;
@end

#endif /* NSMenu_h */
```

Don't forget to import `NSMenu.h` into the Bridging header!

```
#import "NSMenu.h"
```

Then, you can call the proxy method in Swift like this:

```swift
let menu = NSMenu()
menu.addItem(menuItem)
menu._setHasPadding(false, onEdge: 1)
menu._setHasPadding(false, onEdge: 3)
```